# Have a guid column map to several entity types (EF6 fluent mapping)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

**Question rephrased:** I can also reconsider the database design of the *ExternalSupplierMapping* table so the real question is; How can I have a **one to many relation** where the many part can reside in **different tables** that shares a **base class** in Entity framework.

**Old question**

I have this database Table

*ExternalSupplierMapping* (Not: Mapping in name has nothing todo with EF mapping, its a mapping between our internal domain and external suppliers domain (API))

- Int Id (PK)
- Int InternalId (FK with constaint to a specific table)
- Guid ExternalId (FK with No constraint)

We have different tables for the ExternalId depending on supplier

They share a base class class in EF - *Supplier*

- Guid Id
- String Name

This base class has no corresponding table in database, the sub classes do however

I would like to have have a EF entity mapped to the *ExternalSupplierMapping* table

It should look like

- Int Id
- Internal Internal
- Supplier Supplier

In the fluent mapping I guess I have to create one mapping for each entity type that inherits Supplier but I do not know the syntax for it.

Is it even possible? Or do I need to create a untyped Entity like

- Int Id
- Int InternalId
- Guid ExternalId

And do the Join manually when doing a query? This will be easy to fix but not so nice I want to be able todo

```
dbSet.Add(new ExternalSupplierMapping { Internal = internal, Supplier = fooSupplier /* Sub class that inherits Supplier */ });
```

I guess its something like this, but I have only used Map for non materlized relation tables

```
HasRequired(sm => sm.Supplier)
    .WithMany()
    .Map(m =>
    {

    });
```

Comment: Why not just create an extra configuration for each type that is deriving from the parent? Or is that the specific task you're having trouble with

Comment: I have one configuration for each Supplier entity, but the problem is the configuarion for the table that connects our Internal structure with the external supplier (ExternalSupplierMapping)

Comment: rephrased the question I hope its easier to understand what I want